# installing habari

Tags: habari

I am getting an error on installing habari:

> The installer couldn't verify your
>   settings, possibly because your server
>   is not correctly configured. See the
>   manual for information on how to
>   correct this problem, or continue
>   without database verification

Any idea on what the problem could be? I am quite sure that the database information I am putting is correct.

Comment: sorry about that. I am on lighthttpd, mysql, version 0.6.3

Comment: anyway, i've fixed it using this link http://wiki.habariproject.org/en/Installation_using_LiteSpeed It turns out that habari doesn't write the .htaccess. Everything worked out well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . index.php [PT]
```

Habari doesn't write the htaccess. I manually added this and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball is a little hazy.

Please provide the following information:

- Platform: Linux, Windows, MacOS, OpenSolaris ?
- Hosting provider ?
- Database: MySQL, SQLite or Postgres (include version number) ?
- Web Server: Apache, Lighttp, Nginx ?
- PHP version and configured extensions - a link to the output of phpinfo() is always very useful.
- Habari version - latest stable version or trunk ? If the latter, specify the exact SVN version number.

Also consider cross posting to the Habari [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/habari-users?lnk=iggc) where you are likely to get prompt assistance from other Habari users.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write manually the HTACCESS. 
here:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . index.php [PT]